# Dynamic route generation in NextJS 12

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, routes

I have a JS object like so

```
[
    {
        name: 'About',
        path: '/about'
    },
    {
        name: 'Profile',
        path: '/profile'
    },
    {
        name: 'Users',
        path: '/users'
    }
]
```

Is there any way for me to link the paths in this object to the pages I have in my pages folder

I tried using the `Link` component and passing it `as` prop. This handles the navigation but when the page is refreshed it redirects to the 404 page

Answer (score 0):

Go into your **next.config.js** file and add this:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

That should fix this issue of 404 when refreshing. As for passing a prop to Link component, that's fine as it is.

Here's a [next.js explanation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash) as reference.